# Azure download with GetSharedAccessSignature of large file

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, download, azure-storage

Through a webpage, I want to allow users to download (very large) file stored on Azure Cloud storage. I use the GetSharedAccessSignature to allow users to download it (note: the Container is protected and not publicly readable).
I use the following code:

```
// get the file blob
// CloudBlockBlob blob set previously and check (it exists)

        string sas = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(
            new SharedAccessPolicy() { 
                Permissions = SharedAccessPermissions.Read,
                SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5),
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(54) 
            });

        Response.Redirect(blob.Attributes.Uri.AbsoluteUri + sas);
```

This works EXCEPT when the download takes more than 1 hour (as I said, very large files being downloaded over not so good internet connection...).
If the download takes longer, a time-out occurs and the download stops as the Shared Access Expired Time has passed.

How can I solve this?

Kind regards,
Robbie De Sutter

Comment: Just a small tip; you should not set the StartTime unless you intend to have it in the future. This will avoid any time sync issues between servers.

Answer (score 0):

From the code, it seems that you're actually letting the browser do the download. In that scenario, I believe the option is to have shared access signatures valid for longer duration.

Yet another idea is to have your code read the chunks of the blob and then transmit those chunks. That way if there's a need you could create a new SAS URI and use that if the SAS URI timeout has expired and the blob has not downloaded completely.

Take a look at sample code below. Basically in this sample, I have a 200 MB blob. In loop, my code reads 1 MB chunk of the blob and sends that chunk down.

```
        protected void ButtonDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var blobUri = "http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/abc/test2.vhd?sr=b&st=2012-08-17T10%3A29%3A46Z&se=2012-08-17T11%3A29%3A46Z&sp=r&sig=dn7cnFhP1xAPIq0gH6klc4nifqgk7jfOgb0hV5Koi4g%3D";
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(blobUri);
        var blobSize = 200 * 1024 * 1024;
        int blockSize = 1024 * 1024;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM";
        System.String disHeader = "Attachment; Filename=\"" + blockBlob.Name + "\"";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", disHeader);
        for (long offset = 0; offset < blobSize; offset += blockSize)
        {
            using (var blobStream = blockBlob.OpenRead())
            {
                if ((offset + blockSize) > blobSize)
                    blockSize = (int)(blobSize - offset);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[blockSize];
                blobStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
                Response.Flush();
            }
        }
        Response.End();
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wrt the first solution (make the expiration time longer): this is not possible as the maximum duration that can be set is 1 hour. If you set it longer than one hour, you receive the Azure error message "Access without signed identifier cannot have time window more than 1 hour".

Comment: With the release of latest REST API, it is possible to have a SAS URL valid for longer than 1 hour (only in Cloud Storage with SDK 1.7.1). You can read more about it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/12/introducing-table-sas-shared-access-signature-queue-sas-and-update-to-blob-sas.aspx

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, I'm now using the 1.7.1.0 and it appears to be working (however, I was supprised by the breaking changes between 1.7.0.0 and 1.7.1.0 such as "container.CreateIfNotExist();" gives the error "container already exists". Still it's working currently.... I do still have another issue wrt IE9, but I'll post that in a separate question.

Comment: Surprisingly I also ran into the same issue with CreateIfNotExist(). I'm assuming it only happened when you debug the application.